# Generate k fold Cross validation sets F#

Tags: f#, fold

I would like to know how to generate k fold cross validation sets. I would like to know if it can be done through a higher order function such as fold, avoiding recursion. **From a matrix or array, generate 3 subsets (same size) randomly**. Any ideas ??

```
         val matrizz : Matrix<float> =
           DenseMatrix 6x5-Double
         5,1  3,5  1,4  0,2  -1
         4,9    3  1,4  0,2  -1
         4,7  3,2  1,3  0,2  -1
         4,6  3,1  1,5  0,2  -1
         5    3,6  1,4  0,2  -1
         5,4  3,9  1,7  0,4  -1
```

Comment: An example would be good: a sample input (not too large, maybe 3 or 4 rows/columns) and what you'd expect as output. That would help people answer your question; as it is, it's a little vague and hard to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a way to implement it using high order functions like fold or map. I edited the post to better explain what I intend.

Comment: I still don't understand what output you want. Should the subsets contain one item from each column, from randomly-chosen rows? One item from each row, from randomly-chosen columns? One entire row, but which row is randomly chosen?

Comment: I expressed myself badly, sorry. My English is not very good. I want three new matrices the same size as the original but with the rows in random order.  I would like to know if it can be done through a higher order function such as fold or map, avoiding recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that your question is vague, so I'm taking my best guess here. It's not a particularly nice or efficient solution, but it might get you started.

```
let chooseBut (array: 'a[][]) index =
    [| for i=0 to (array.Length - 1) do if i <> index then yield array.[i] |]
    |> Array.concat

let kfoldSplit k (input: 'a[]) =
    let partition = Array.chunkBySize (input.Length/k) input
    [ 0..k-1 ]
    |> List.map (chooseBut partition)

[| 1..50 |]
|> kfoldSplit 5
```

Note that this might not produce the expected result for an input array such as `[|1..52|]`.

**Edit:** A version without list comprehension

```
let chooseBut array index =
    array
    |> Array.mapi (fun i v -> if i <> index then (Some v) else None)
    |> Array.choose id
    |> Array.concat
```

Also, to get random partiontions you can do

```
let partition = Array.chunkBySize 5 [| 1..50 |]
partition.SelectPermutation()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a way to implement it using high order functions like fold or map. I edited the post to better explain what I intend.

Comment: @Harry you keep saying you don't want to use recursion, but there is no recursion in my answer. At least not in an obvious form. List.map probably uses recursion under the hood. So why do you want to use fold or map?

Comment: @Harry Also, if you just want the rows in a random order use Array.permute or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use F# lists (lists of lists of numbers), because that's easier to start with than matrices. So, assuming we have a sample input and a random number generator:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let inputMatrix = 
  [ [ 1.1; 1.2; 1.3 ]
    [ 2.1; 2.2; 2.3 ]
    [ 3.1; 3.2; 3.3 ] ]
```

I think the easiest way to generate a list that has the rows in random order is to iterate over the rows with `List.map`, generate random number for each row and then sort the rows:

```
inputMatrix 
|> List.map (fun row -> rnd.Next(), row)
|> List.sortBy fst
|> List.map snd
```

This is pretty functional and I think it is quite readable, so it would be my preferred solution. It needs a couple of iterations over the list, so you cannot do this with just one `fold`.

You could solve this using `fold`, but then you need a different strategy. You could iterate over the rows and insert the current row at random point in a new matrix that you build as you walk over the rows:

```
([], inputMatrix) 
||> List.fold (fun matrix row -> 
  let split = rnd.Next(matrix.Length + 1)
  List.take split matrix @ [row] @ List.skip split matrix)
```

This starts with an empty matrix `[]` and each step over the `inputMatrix` picks a splitting point and inserts the new row there. This part is quite inefficient, but it's a solution using `fold`.

Note that this is all nice functional way of doing things, but if you care about efficient matrix operations, it's probably better to do some lower-level imperative coding for such a basic function - unless the library you're using provides it already.